# Storing documents in Oracle CLOB table vs NAS mount in the Openshift

Tags: java, spring-boot, file-upload

I have a scenario, where I need to temporarily store the documents which gets uploaded from an angular UI before uploading to the organization's document store. I am looking for options and got two solutions

1. Store the uploaded file into the existing Oracle database in a CLOB column
2. Store the uploaded file to the NAS path associated with the Openshift (We are deploying our code as docker images in the Openshift environment)

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: Yeah.. Question is more like what are the pros and cons of storing document in a CLOB column of Oracle DB ?